# simple mysql select and insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have no idea why this isn't working. I've taken code from a previous project that works fine. I just want to select specific columns. Here's what im trying...

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT  when, where, name FROM tablename ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

    //I dont really know how to debug php well, so this is all I have to go by to know if its not working.  
    if (!$result) 
    {
         echo "<p>Page load has failed please try again</p>";
    }
```

if I select all like this it works fine:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
```

If im doing an insert, that doesn't work either...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (when, where, name) VALUES ('$when' , '$where' , '$name');";
mysql_query($query);
```

I'm sure the spelling is correct i've looked at it several times, and even if I put

```
echo $row["name"]; and the others ect while using the select all * they appear...
```

It just seems like its happening when im selecting individual columns.

I have other tables, with other sites using the same exact code and its working fine.

How can i fix this? or at least how can i debug the php to get some better error messages?

edit:
I'm sure the values going in are good, its just simple helloworld string
I've tried including count in the select incase that needed to be there for the sort, but that didnt make it work.

Comment: how are you getting the $when? is it from a post or get method?

Comment: for the sake of testing im just manually inputting helloworld for each value

Comment: Print out the error from MySQL (`mysql_error()`) for any of these queries to see exactly where the error is. `mysql_query` returns false when there is an error. I have answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word `where` is a reserved word (the `WHERE` clause of `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries). So is `when`. `count` is a built-in function name but can be used as an identifier, though you shouldn't.

If you use it as an identifier, you must always enclose it in `backticks` in the query. I recommend not using parts of the query language as column names.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Make sense I thought for sure that would have fixed it but it didnt, I updated my code to remove the use of the word where, but i'm still having the same issue. The select wont work unless I do *

Comment: whoops, nvm i changed the where but not when...fixed it and its all great now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WHERE, WHEN and COUNT are reserved MySQL words (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html). Use backticks like this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `where`, `when`, name FROM tablename ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
```

Comment: Make sense I thought for sure that would have fixed it but it didnt, I updated my code to remove the use of the word where, but i'm still having the same issue. The select wont work unless I do *

Comment: whoops, nvm i changed the where but not when...fixed it and its all great now. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`where` is a reserved sql word, use `tablename.where` to select the correct column.

Comment: `'where'` is the literal string *where*. You enclose identifiers in \`backticks\` not single quotes.